# How to create `if in` function check?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been investigating and found out that using `if in` is the fastest compare to -> [image]

[benchmark](https://perfpy.com/71#/)

and I have been trying to create a function where I can pass arguments on what path I want the `if in` will follow e.g.

```
def main():
    d = {"foo": "spam"}
    if "bar" in d:
        if "eggs" in d["bar"]:
            d["bar"]["eggs"]
        else:
            {}
    else:
        {}
```

But instead of having a long code, I was trying to do a function where I can pass argument e.g. `get_path(json_data, 'foo', 'eggs')` which would try to do something similar to the code above and return if value found else return empty.

My question is how can I create a function where we can pass argument to do the `if in` checks and return the value if it's found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass your `keys` as `tuple/list`:

```
def main(data, keys):
    for k in keys:
        if k not in data:
            return {}
        data = data[k]
    return data


d = {"foo": "spam", "bar": {"eggs": "HAM!"}}
print(main(d, ('bar', 'eggs')))
```

Out:

```
HAM!
```

Comment: I did a new benchmark to see and here is the result -> https://perfpy.com/73 - As you can see, you are not far away from Exception/Get but I guess thats due to all the loops it need to go through right?=

Comment: @ProtractorNewbie: Yes. You hardcoded everything, which is always faster than a dynamic approach.

Comment: Make sense - Althrough I think your suggestion was the best performed too and pretty simple as well to understand :) I like it!

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice little problem that has a fairly easy solution as long as everything is dicts:

```
def get_path(data, *path):
    node = data
    for step in path:
        if step in node:
            node = node[step]
        else:
            return {} # None might be more appropriate here
    return node
```

note that it won't work quite right if you encounter a list along the way: although lists support `[]` and they support `in`, `in` *means something different* to them ("is this value found", rather than "is  this key found"), so the test generally won't succeed.

Comment: I did a new benchmark to see and here is the result -> https://perfpy.com/73 - as you can see your suggestion would be ranked as last in benchmark but I assume its due to longer checks right?